# Items in ArrayList overwriting

Tags: android, arraylist, uri

Can someone explain why items are overwriting in the ArrayList ?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        selectedImage = data.getData();

            ALofSelectedImgs = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            ALofSelectedImgs.add(selectedImage);

    }
}
```

"selectedImage" is the Uri I get after choosing a picture from the the phones gallery. I want to store more than one Uri inside the ArrayList. Why is it overwriting?

Comment: Can you show your full code please? If this snippet is inside a loop then every time you are creating new ArrayList and adding one item to it. Thus at any point you have only one item in the List.

Comment: Edited. onActivityResult is called right after choosing an image from the gallery.

Comment: The problem here is you are creating a new ArrayList on every `onActivityResult` call. That's why a new ArrayList is created every time and the earlier value is lost. If you can tell what exactly you are trying to achieve we can probably suggest a better way to do that.

Comment: Awesome, I have declared the ArrayList outside of the onActivityResult. It works now! ^^ Anyway, what I'm trying to do, is just add Images from the gallery into a gridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of your arraylist is local. So each time you attempt to add to it, a new arraylist is created, hence previous values in the previous list are lost.

```
ALofSelectedImgs = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ALofSelectedImgs.add(selectedImage);
```

So declare and initialise your arraylist outside of your onactivityresult

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy and really mad at the same time. This little change was all I had to do and I spent so much time looking for it!

Comment: yea, I guess. ^^
One more thing though, As I mentioned above, I'm adding pictures from the gallery into a gridView, after loading a bunch of them, the app gets VERY laggy, even crashes most of the time (happens when adding images taken by the phones camera; small images from the web are working just fine), how do I fix this ?